# location of vector Taylor expansion remainder

Tags: taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

I know in 1-dimension case, $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(\tilde{x_0})(x-x_0)$$ where $\tilde{x_0}$ lies between $x$ and $x_0$.

What about in k-dimension case? $$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)+\mathbf{f}'(\tilde{\mathbf{x}_0})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)$$
Does $\mathbf{\tilde{x}}_0$ still lies between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}_0$?

If $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow\mathbf{x}_0$, does $\mathbf{\tilde{x}}_0\rightarrow\mathbf{x}_0$?

Comment: The 1D case is a form of the mean value theorem. What do you expect for $k$ dimensions? What will happen to the derivative? What could "between" mean, as $x$ and $x_0$ are now points in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb C$ which can be treated as $\mathbb R^{2}$. Consider teh function $f(z)=e^{z}$. $e^{0}-e^{2\pi i}=0$ cannot be written as $2\pi i e^{z}$ for any $z$.